# @font-face problems on remote

Tags: css, font-face

I am trying to load this custom font, and cannot get it to work on my server. I am just serving static files. This is the exact syntax I am using, and it works perfectly on my local machine.

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "Telegrafico";
  src: url('/assets/fonts/telegrafico.woff') format('woff'), url('/assets/fonts/telegrafico.eot') format('embedded-opentype'), url('/assets/fonts/telegrafico.ttf') format('truetype'), url('/assets/fonts/telegrafico.svg') format('svg');
}
```

The issues are in all browsers...I cannot figure out for the life of me what is wrong.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Look in the console, like Google Chrome inspector. It will highlight a http error if present, or at least you can actually check the webserver is returning the expected file

Comment: no http error as far as I can see. How can I tell if it is returning the file?

Comment: In Chrome inspector you get this https://www.evernote.com/shard/s45/sh/6684b5aa-2ec3-4917-a285-9cea6c406c6d/5c5dbd556360efefb8e2caf92d4f8c0d make sure you have actually uploaded the font files

Comment: restarted the browser and cleared the cache and now I'm getting a 404...but the files are absolutely there, i checked.

Comment: Is the site live so one can investigate?

Comment: no, but I think I have figured it out...the absolute path is not actually going to the root of the site, it's going to an ancestor of it.
Is there any way to set the root?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45352/discussion-between-ryan-chipman-and-barry-carlyon)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From our chat.

You are using a absolute URL in your CSS.
However on live your site is being served from a sub directory.
(The error here being a mismatch between the model of your local site and the live environment)

Solution is to use a relative path in your CSS instead of a absolute one.

So assuming /assets/css and /assets/fonts

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "Telegrafico";
  src: url('../fonts/telegrafico.woff') format('woff'), url('../fonts/telegrafico.eot') format('embedded-opentype'), url('../fonts/telegrafico.ttf') format('truetype'), url('../fonts/telegrafico.svg') format('svg');
}
```

Should suffice